# Extracting web link titles in order to name lists

Tags: r, xml

I have the following data:

```
url = getURL("https://www.fomento.gob.es/be2/?nivel=2&orden=34000000")

parsed <- htmlParse(url)

links <- xpathSApply(parsed,path = "//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
hrefLinks = xpathSApply(parsed,path = "//a")

xlsLinks <- hrefLinks[grep('.XLS|.xls', links, value = FALSE)]

xlsLinks
```

Which gives me something like:

```
[[31]]
<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020150.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre</a> 

[[32]]
<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020160.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3.1  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre nueva</a> 

[[33]]
<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020170.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3.2  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de segunda mano</a> 

[[34]]
<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020180.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.4   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de extranjeros residentes en España</a>
```

I want to extract the "titles" of each of the list links. i.e. for the above 4 examples I would like to extract:

1. `3.3   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre`
2. `3.3.1  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre nueva`
3. `3.3.2  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de segunda mano`
4. `3.4   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de extranjeros residentes en España`

In the full list there are `34` such types that I would like to extract. They all correspond to the URLS with the extension `xls`. The idea is to use these values to name the lists of URLS.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37687435/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rvest and then an attribute = value css selector with $ ends with operator to target the desired elements (adding a parent element id as an anchor for safety net). As the `i` case insensitivity flag isn't supported in rvest implementation, you will need to provide OR syntax to cater for upper/lowercase substrings within href attribute. You can then use `html_text()` for the titles of the returned nodeList.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

url <- "https://www.fomento.gob.es/be2/?nivel=2&orden=34000000"
df <-
  map_dfr(
    read_html(url) %>%
      html_elements('#app_camaleon [href$=".xls"], #app_camaleon [href$=".XLS"]'),
    ~ data.frame(
      title = .x %>% html_text(),
      link = .x %>% html_attr("href") %>% url_absolute(url)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Split and get 3rd item:

```r
x <- list(
  '<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020150.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre</a>',
  '<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020160.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3.1  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre nueva</a>',
  '<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020170.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.3.2  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de segunda mano</a>',
  '<a target="_blank" href="sedal/34020180.XLS" title="Enlace a un archivo con extensión .xls. Este enlace abre una ventana nueva">3.4   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de extranjeros residentes en España</a>')

sapply(x, function(i) strsplit(i, "[<>]")[[ 1 ]][ 3 ])
# [1] "3.3   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre"                                    
# [2] "3.3.1  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre nueva"                             
# [3] "3.3.2  Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de segunda mano"                   
# [4] "3.4   Valor medio de las transacciones inmobiliarias de vivienda libre de extranjeros residentes en España"
```